# Outputting similar characters from two Strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I would like to compare two user-defined strings and output the count of the number of characters shared between the two strings, without resorting to using arrays. I then need to output each of those characters. I understand the user-input part using a `Scanner`, but afterwards I am clueless. Pseudocode will suffice if you dont feel like giving the actual code.

For example, "hamper" as string1, and "happened" as string2 would return

## of shared characters = 4 (5)

shared charactors >> "h", "a", "p", "e" ("h", "a", "p", "p", "e",  "e")

(either way would suffice)

Comment: "the same characters that appear in them" could you be more specific? like do they need to be on the same index or just in the string no matter what index, or?

Comment: If you could show some code that you've tried and say specifically what you're having difficulty with, we might be able to help. As a suggestion to start: If you had two sequences of characters in front of you on a piece of paper, how would you solve this problem yourself? Once you know how you would solve it, step by step, try writing some code to follow the same steps.

Comment: I think two things are needed: 1) sample inputs and outputs. What do you expect to get if you compare "banana" with "rockband", for example? A few of those would help a lot. And 2) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't know, but i think this question is better to be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming not unique matches:

```
//get word1
//get word2
//set variable for character count:  count = 0
//for each character in word1
    //for each character in word2
        //if the characters are the same
            //print character
            //increment count
//print count
```

Assuming only unique matches:

```
//get word1
//get word2
//set variable for character count:  count = 0
//create empty list of already found characters:  found_list = {}
//for each character in word1
    //for each character in word2
        //if the characters are the same
            //if character is not in found_list
                //print character
                //add character to found_list
                //increment count
//print count
```

I would recommend looking up `for loops` and `.charAt()` method:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29

Comment: No it doesn't answer the question, i am afraid

Comment: @Sage:  How doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: The OP is asking for counting the characters

Comment: He is not sure that scanner takes user input. and you think that this answers his question?

Comment: The truth is his question is not clear at all. what if `accca` and `acb` compared it. How come the OP will count the matching character? he has not clarified those

Comment: Basically you need one while-loop, which goes through both words in parallel. How exactly, question does not have enough detail, but two nested loops is certainly wrong.

Comment: he he! That is what i was pointing to the poster :)

Comment: actually it did answer my question precisely. thank you.  And I clearly stated i understood the scanner hasan.  I was taught to do it with arrays though, and i was told not to use an array, so thats why im clueless.